# Hide TopTabs when scrolling a Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, modern-ui, xamarin.forms.shell

I am developing a complex App and made use of the advantages of Xamarin.Forms.Shell for layout and navigation. Now there are a few annoying things that I haven't been able to find a solution for yet.

I have three Sections in the App where two or more Pages   are displayed as TopTabs (one Tab-Object holding multiple ContentPage-Objects). Now, while the user scrolls through the elements of one of these Pages I want the TopTabs to disappear. But I couldn't find anything related to TopTabs. Hiding the whole Navigation Bar is not what I want to achieve. Just the tabs should Ease out, once scrolling and ease back in when Scrolling is finished or the top of the `Listview` becomes  visible.

Maybe somebody out there has found a solution and wants to share it with me. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: in SO "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." better to break unrelated questions into new separate question, to avoid your question to be closed under [Needs more focus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You could invoke the line  `Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);`  when scrolling the list and set it to true when stopping .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62079904/7149454

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT This will hide the _bottom-tabs_, yes. But I want the _Top-Tabs_ to disappear. Those that are created when multiple `ContentPages` are combined within one bottom Tab.

Comment: @NickKovalsky I'm afraid the `Sharpnado.Presentations.Forms`-Tabs are not compatible with `Xamarin.Forms.Shell`.

Comment: Well shell is for using xamarin quick out-of-the box, putting too much constraints on your design. Would advise to not even spend time writing code for it, to be dropped one day anyway for your custom navigation system once you get some complicated pixel-perfect ui to implement.

Comment: @NickKovalsky You may indeed have a point in that. I will try a custom approach on those special Toptabs and share the result if I succeed. I am definitely still a beginner in Xamarin Forms. Nevertheless, it feels kind of chunky if you understand what I mean.  I thought about switching to frameworks like Ionic but porting a complete app probably is rubbish and wouldn't work so I stick to XF for now.

Comment: it may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65554298